# Is it possible to change inside a function from somewhere else?

Tags: php

I want to do something like this:

I have a function like this that I don't know what exactly inside it, I just know that the function should have a parameter and one return, it may have if statement, foreach or anything. I want to get function find that parameter and return, and specify it's code:

```
function a($param) {
     if($param > 1) {
         return $param;
      }
}
```

and I want to pass this function to another function and edit it and then call it:

```
function b(a($param)) {
     // get function code
     // change return in that function to something else like echo
     // specify if statements and anything else and change to what I want
     // and then call it and use it
}
```

Is this possible in php?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, at the moment you seem to have an idea about changing the source code in a function.  It would help if you give an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible in php?

Yes, that is called *code re-use*. The idea is to re-use the existing function *but not* modifying it's code. You can have your function, too, thought.

Let's take the `echo` example as it's that straight forward:

```php
echo a($param);
```

Done.

Now that is perhaps too trivial in your case. So why not write a function your own?:

```php
function b($param) {
     $result = a($param);

     // ... do whatever you want with the result ...

     return $result; // finally return.
}
```

And then:

```php
echo b($param); // use your function instead of the other.
```

This is a common way to re-use the code of functions *within* your own code.

If the original function is not doing what you need, take a different one that does or communicate with its author(s) to raise your issue(s).

---

Now what if it is not always `a()` but maybe `a1()`, `a2()`, ..., `aN()` to be used in `b()`?

One way to handle this is to abstract from `a()` by making it a function parameter of `b()`:

```php
function b(callable $a, $param) {
    $result = $a($param);

    // ... do whatever you want with the result ...

    return $result; // finally return.
}
```

Now `b()` can be called with any kind-of-`a()` function and its `$param`.

This might not fully suffice in your case but perhaps opens up a direction you can benefit from.

Let's see.

Perhaps the additional parameter `$a` stands in the way when calling `b()`.

Previously it was:

```php
echo a($param);
```

Then:

```php
echo b($param);
```

And it now became:

```php
$a = 'a' . random_int(1, 99); // $a could be any-kind-of-a()

// ...

echo b($a, $param);
```

Now similar to having a function as a parameter to make it "dynamic", it is also possible in PHP to have it as a return value: A function that returns a function:

```php
function b_of_a(callable $a): callable {
    // b()'s original implementation (enclosing $a)
    return function ($param) use ($a) {
        $result = $a($param);

        // ... do whatever you want with the result ...

        return $result; // finally return.
    };
};
```

Similar to `a() -> $a()` there is now `b() -> $b()`:

```php
$a = 'a' . random_int(1, 99); // $a could be any-kind-of-a()

// ...

$b = b_of_a($a); // b() with any-kind-of-a() as $b 

// ...

echo $b($param);
```

What were fixed function names in the original code have become variables you can pass around. The way both the kind-of-`a()` and the kind-of-`b()` function calls are preserved: with the single parameter.

And while the code of `b()` is fixed, what is `a()` within it, can be injected as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much, thats the point, that I dont know whats inside the first function, and I want to change it not use its result, I'm making somethin that user should create function and pass it to my function and I want to specify whats inside it so change everything inside it. if I want to be more clear, mu actual problem in my project is the user function(first function) should get an array from database that I passed to it and do what they want in it and then return all rows. for this I think I have to change first function that I dont know anything about inside it and should specify it.

Comment: Ah, okay. You might be looking for something called [_Inversion of Control (IoC)_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). That is perfectly possible with PHP, too, also on function level, but the way you describe it, I'm not sure I fully grasp your example. I think I'll extend the answer a bit thought.